# How to automate Reactjs drop downs using Watir

Tags: reactjs, watir

Currently, I am working with a reactjs web application and it has many dropdowns throughout the application, the normal dropdown (select) approach doesn't work because the options to select are dynamically loaded from react dropdown component, but for the moment I tried to sort out by using keystroke like this:

```
@browser.text_field(name: "countries").set("Germany");sleep1
@browser.text_field(name: "countries").send_keys :enter
```

I am writing into the textfield and wait until the expected text appears then use the keystroke.

Below is the HTML, I know it doesn't help to any extent:

```
<div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input name="countries" data-test-id="countries" autocomplete="0" aria-activedescendant="react-select-7--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 16px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div></div>
```

However, I see this is not the best solution any suggestions or solutions would be very helpful.

Comment: It would help if you can share the exact implementation of the dropdown you are working with (eg a self-contained example or demo page). There are a number of libraries that do dropdowns and autocompletes - each with their differences for automating via Watir. However, the general approach will be same as what you have.

Comment: I will try to share the implementation as soon as possible, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the enter key upon that option not on the text field. May be something like this.

```
 @browser.text_field(name: "countries").set("Germany");sleep1
 @browser.element(text: "Germany").send_keys :enter
```

You don't need to pass the enter key to be more specific, you can trigger the click instead.

```
 @browser.text_field(name: "countries").set("Germany");sleep1
 @browser.element(text: "Germany").click
```